# DBpedia resource name standard

Tags: dbpedia

Does DBpedia name have any standard or convention?  By that, I mean, e.g., `United Kingdom` has a resource named `United_Kingdom`. But I'm seeing that the fact of having an underscore and having each word being capitalized doesn't hold.  For instance, take `University_of_Manchester`; if you type it as `University_Of_Manchester` with a capital ‘O’ in “of,” you won't get the resource.  Is it obligatory to do a filtering to get the resource name in the proper case, because we may want to make all letters lowercase, have underscore in spaces and just make a query because doing in filtering in the SPARQL do takes some time.

Any suggestions? I've just started to learn about DBpedia, so I may be missing something.

Comment: Did the answer suit your needs?  If it did, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/225437) to let others know that it worked for you.  If it didn't, please let us know why, so that it can be improved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBpedia encodes the information available in Wikipedia, and its naming convention is based on the names of Wikipedia articles.  The DBpedia wiki page, [The DBpedia Data Set](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets#h18-4), says, in Section [3. Denoting or Naming “Things”](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets#h18-4):

> Each thing in the DBpedia data set is denoted by a de-referenceable IRI- or URI-based reference of the form http://dbpedia.org/resource/Name, where Name is derived from the URL of the source Wikipedia article, which has the form http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name. Thus, each DBpedia entity is tied directly to a Wikipedia article. Every DBpedia entity name resolves to a description-oriented Web document (or Web resource).
>
> Until DBpedia release 3.6, we only used article names from the English Wikipedia, but since DBpedia release 3.7, we also provide Internationalized Datasets that contain IRIs like http://xx.dbpedia.org/resource/Name, where xx is a Wikipedia language code and Name is taken from the source URL, http://xx.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name.

Thus, since the Wikipedia article is [University of Manchester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Manchester), not [University Of Manchester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_Of_Manchester), the DBpedia resource is http://dbpedia.org/page/University_of_Manchester, and not http://dbpedia.org/page/University_Of_Manchester.