# Getting list of actors from dbpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have trying to solve this task where I have to retrieve the list of actors for a given film name. I am new to both SPARQL and dbpedia.

After reading some tutorials, so far I have the following:

```
PREFIX dbpo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?actor_name
WHERE {
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
    "Total Recall" dbpo:movieTitle  ?movieName .
    ?movieName dbpo:actor ?actor.
    ?actor dbpo:actor_name ?actor_name.
  }
}
```

Perhaps I am getting the names wrong.

On a general note, how should I go about finding specific service points from dbpedia, such as the one described in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you were getting the properties that you were using in your query, as they don't appear to be used on the relevant resources.  An additional problem is that, although SPARQL allows it as a triple pattern, literals can't be subjects of RDF triples, which you'd need in order to match

```
"Total Recall" dbpo:movieTitle  ?movieName .
```

This triple, if it were legal, would be the assertion that the *string* "Total Recall" has some movie title, and would bind the variable `?movieName` to that title.  A string isn't a movie though, so it probably wouldn't have a movie title, either.

In this particular case, take a look at the information that DBpedia has on Total Recall by visiting

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Total_Recall, which actually redirects to
- http://dbpedia.org/page/Total_Recall

You'll see some triples of the form

```
dbpprop:starring dbpedia:Ronny_Cox
dbpprop:starring dbpedia:Arnold_Schwarzenegger
```

which suggests that you'd want a query like:

```
select ?actorName where { 
  ?film rdfs:label "Total Recall"@en ;
        dbpprop:starring ?actor .
  ?actor rdfs:label ?actorName .
  filter(langMatches(lang(?actorName),"en"))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?actorName%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20?film%20rdfs:label%20%22Total%20Recall%22@en%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpprop:starring%20?actor%20.%0D%0A%20%20?actor%20rdfs:label%20?actorName%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28langMatches%28lang%28?actorName%29,%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

That query is suitable for plugging into the [public DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), but if you're running locally and want to use the `service` keyword to federate the query, you would do it with `service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>`:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

select ?actorName where { 
  service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
    ?film rdfs:label "Total Recall"@en ;
          dbpprop:starring ?actor .
    ?actor rdfs:label ?actorName .
    filter(langMatches(lang(?actorName),"en"))
  }
}
```

In general, one of the best ways to see what kinds of classes and properties are used in DBpedia is to exploit the fact that DBpedia has a naming convention for resources, as discussed in [DBpedia resource name standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15713525/1281433), so given a Wikipedia article `XYZ`, you can retrieve `http://dbpedia.org/resource/XYZ` and look at the data.  For ontology classes and properties, you can also see the [documentation about the ontology](http://dbpedia.org/Ontology), and [browse the ontology classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15713525/1281433).  For interactive queries, the [public SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) is very useful.

Comment: One of my query is, how I could actually get the available properties.

Comment: I just updated my answer with some links to the ontology documentation.  For finding properties, I've found that the most useful thing to do it to visit some of the resources you're interested in and actually look at the properties that have been used with them.

Comment: so, for the service endpoint, I should use: "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Total_Recall"

Comment: No, the endpoint it http://dbpedia.org/sparql .  The IRI of the resource that you're interested asking about is http://dbpedia.org/resource/Total_Recall .

Comment: So, looking into the IRI would give a list of available properties, but the overall service endpoint is always " dbpedia.org/sparql", right?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz Yes.  I've updated my answer to include (like you did) a query that includes `service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36747/discussion-between-shamim-hafiz-and-joshua-taylor)